# get list items inside div tag using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a html like this

```
<div id="all-stories" class="book"> 
<ul>

<li title="Book1"  ><a href="book1_url">Book1</a></li>

<li title="Book2"  ><a href="book2_url">Book2</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I want to get the books and their respective url using xpath, but it seems my approach is not working. for simplicity  i tried to extract all the elements under "li " tags as follows

```
lis = tree.xpath('//div[@id="all-stories"]/div/text()')
```

Comment: Don't you want `//div[@id="all-stories"]/ul/li/text()`?

Comment: @kgraney I tried the approach but  didnt get me the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import lxml.html as LH

content = '''\
<div id="all-stories" class="book"> 
<ul>

<li title="Book1"  ><a href="book1_url">Book1</a></li>

<li title="Book2"  ><a href="book2_url">Book2</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
'''
root = LH.fromstring(content)
for atag in root.xpath('//div[@id="all-stories"]//li/a'):
    print(atag.attrib['href'], atag.text_content())
```

yields

```
('book1_url', 'Book1')
('book2_url', 'Book2')
```

---

The XPath `//div[@id="all-stories"]/div` does not match anything because there is no child `div` inside the outer `div` tag.

The XPath `//div[@id="all-stories"]/li` also would not match because the there is no *direct* child `li` tage inside the `div` tag. However, `//div[@id="all-stories"]//li` *does* match `li` tags because `//` tells XPath to recursively search as deeply as necessary to find the `li` tags.

Now, the content you are looking for is not in the `li` tag. It is inside the `a` tag. So instead use the XPath
`'//div[@id="all-stories"]//li/a'` to reach the `a` tags.
The value of the `href` attribute can be accessed with `atag.attrib['href']`, and the text with `atag.text_content()`.

Comment: my html has a part like this: `<ul id="ABC"><li>172</li><li>68</li></ul>`. I wrote my code like this: `for li in tree.xpath('//ul[@id="ABC"]//li'):` ; `print li.text_contet()` But nothing prints out.

Comment: Except for the spelling error (`text_contet` --> `text_content`), your code looks fine. Here's a runnable version of your code which prints 172 and 68: https://ideone.com/cBmjrM.